# Display 2 images in each row using php mysql

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am trying to fetch the images from the database and display 2 images in each row using php mysql. My code displays only 2 images and rest of the images are not displayed. Here is the code

CSS

```
.image-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

PHP

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from table1");
echo "<div class=view1>";
$i=0;
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            if($i % 4 == 0) {
                echo "<td>"; 
                    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image1'] ).'" class=image-inner height="200" width="200"/>';
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $row['name1'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $row['designation'];
            }
                echo "</td>";
            $i++;
        }
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: stop using deprecated+removed `mysql_*` library. Upgrade to php 7 and use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library

Comment: That code will just create one row with many data. Why not use bootstrap `col-md-6` instead? this will automatically give you 2 images per row

Comment: Your `if($i % 4 == 0) {` should be around the row `<tr>`, not the cell `<td>`

Comment: I used if($i % 4 == 0) { should be around the row <tr> cell it displays all the images in single row.